# tkz-euclide documentation example on arrows gives error

Tags: tikz-arrows, tkz-euclide

I try to implement an example on page 192 of the `tkz-euclide` manual which is supposed to draw several arrows on a circle.  But I get an error.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tikzset{tkz arrows/.style=
    {postaction={on each path={tkz arrow={Latex[scale=2,color=black]}}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B}
  \tkzDrawCircle[tkz arrows](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The error is

`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/on each path', to which you passed 'tkz arrow={Latex[scale=2,color=black]}', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: What is your version of ´tkz-euclide ´?

Comment: How do I look it up?  I have whatever comes with Fedora Linux.  The documentation I took the example from is what I found at CTAN.

Comment: Oops, I now see that I am using directly texlive.  Let me update it to see if the error goes away.

Comment: You need the 4.05 version and you can find it on ctan.

Comment: I updated my texlive 2021 to 2022 and it works.  Package makes my (math  prof) life muuuuch better.  Presently making pics for students in complex analysis.

Comment: The next version 4.2 with a lot of new stuff will arrive in a few days. It will be on ctan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an old version you can add some styles in your file

```
\makeatletter
%<----------------  arrow --------------------------------------–>
% Syntax:
%
%  - tkz arrow=<arrow end tip>`
%  - tkz arrow=<arrow end tip> at <pos> (<pos> = .5 by default)
%  - tkz arrow={<arrow end tip>[<arrow options>] at <pos>}
%
%
% Example usages:
%
% \draw[tkz arrow=Stealth] (A) -- (B);
% \draw[tkz arrow={To[scale=3] at .3}] (A)-- (B);
% \draw[tkz arrow={Latex[scale=5,blue] at .8}] (A)-- (B);

\tikzset{
tkz arrow/.default=Latex,
  tkz arrow/.code=%
  {%
    \pgfutil@in@{ at }{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@
      \mytikz@parsearrow#1\mytikz@stop
    \else
      \mytikz@parsearrow#1 at .5\mytikz@stop
    \fi
  }
}
\def\mytikz@parsearrow#1 at #2\mytikz@stop{%
  \pgfutil@in@{[}{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@
    \mytikz@parsearrow@opt{#2}#1\mytikz@stop
  \else
    \mytikz@parsearrow@opt{#2}#1[]\mytikz@stop
  \fi
}

% #1 = pos, #2 = arrow end tip, #3 = arrow options
\def\mytikz@parsearrow@opt#1#2[#3]\mytikz@stop{%
  \pgfkeysalso{decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[#3]{#2}}
    },
    postaction={decorate}
  }%
}
%<------------------------------------------------------------->
\tikzset{
   on each path/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      }}}}
 %<------------------  arrows --------------------------------------–>          
\tikzset{tkz arrows/.style=%
{postaction={on each path={tkz arrow={Latex[scale=2,color=black]}}}}}  
\makeatother
```